# How can I automatically remove zero weight bones from a model

Tags: bones

I have tried looking it up already and there isnt anything that helps with the issue whatsoever. I just need to know how to remove zero weight bones automatically without needing to go through every single bone in the model, as it would take far too long

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "zero weight bones"? Bones that do not contribute to deformation? Removing bones from a rig may cause loss in functionality. Please share more details (your armature rig , how are bones named, etc.) and example what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Even if they aren't keyframed and don't have any weights assigned they are probably still part of the bone parenting system so removing them might cause unexpected results.